# How to set a minimum length for username in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, username

I need to set a minimum lenght for username in a website that use WooCommerce.

In a "standard" WordPress installation (without WooCommerce, I mean) I could use a snippet like this one:

```
function my_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) 
{
    if ( strlen( $sanitized_user_login ) < 5 ) {
        $errors->add( 'username_too_short', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Username must be at least 5 characters.' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'my_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
```

Unfortunally it doesn't work (I simply tested it with a fake registration) because **WooCommerce has it's own register form and hooks**.

I've found [a palliative solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/minimummaximum-username-input-woocommerce) that suggest to edit the form-login.php file adding a pattern attribute to the input fields `<input pattern=".{3,}" required title="3 characters minimum">`, but I don't want follow this procedure, I'd prefer to edit my functions.php instead.

I found a plugin called ["Network Username Restrictions Override"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/network-username-restrictions-override/) but "it hasn't been updated in over 2 years" and it refers to a network and I think it couldn't fit my situation.

I've also tried to [find another plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=username%20lenght) in WordPress Plugin Directory but I found nothing.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This works for me - are you talking about the default registration area (`wp-login.php?action=register`)? Or did you test in the admin area/custom registration form?

Comment: Hi @TheDeadMedic, thank you for the feedback. In effect the website I'm working on use another page to register use (/my-account). I did not realized it until you tell me. But the hook is not valid the same?

Comment: That will be the issue then. You need to find out what hook(s) your custom registration uses.

Comment: Thank you @TheDeadMedic, I've edited the question and now I'm trying to find out a solution.

Comment: I saw the "put on hold as off-topic" alert. I did not know that the plugins discussion was offtopic - I apologize. It is a real shame because StackExchange is the best place to discuss these issues. Moreover [the community of WooThemes is being disabled](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/community/topics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out the solution.

Because, as I said, WooCommerce has it's own hooks, first of all [I've searched for a WooCommerce hook about registration](http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/2.4.9/hooks/#index=b&search=registration).

I discovered the existence of a hook very similiar to the one used by WordPress: **[woocommerce_registration_errors](http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/2.4.9/filters/woocommerce_registration_errors/)**. Obviously it works in the same way.

Then I simply replaced the WordPress hook with the WooCommerce one. Here the final snippet you have to insert **in your functions.php file**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'my_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function my_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) 
{
    if ( strlen( $sanitized_user_login ) < 5 ) {
        $errors->add( 'username_too_short', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Username must be at least 5 characters.' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}
```